# Exploiting SUID Binary that connects to SSH server

Tags: ssh, privileged-account

While conducting a pentest on a Linux machine, I have a limited shell and trying to escalate privileges.

One interesting thing that i have found is a binary called connect installed under /usr/local/bin/ that has  SUID permissions. Here is the complete output for ls -al:

mark@serv1:/usr/local/bin$ ls -al connect
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 6723 2013-10-10 13:02 connect

When trying to run this binary, it seems that it is trying to connect to an ssh server. here is the output.

mark@serv1:/usr/local/bin$ ./connect
Connecting to x.x.x.x
ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Network is unreachable
lost connection

I am really wondering is there is a way to leverage this to get a root access to the system ? I though that I could utilize this to get a shell of this SUID binary or even trying to ssh root@127.0.0.1 utilizing these permissions. However, I can not figure out how to accomplish this since I am not that much Linux expert.

Thanks

Comment: `strings connect | less ` might help, and `file connect` to get the type. maybe it is just a script you could read.

Comment: Thanks, Actually that was a nice trick although it did not help getting a full root. however, It just turned out that the command that this script runs is "scp -r /tobecopied/* x.x.x.x:/var/www/"    and  the file type is: " setuid ELF 32-bit LSB executable"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If may be vulnerable because it runs the ssh binary without specifying the full path. To test this:

1. Copy bash into a file called ssh in your home directory.
2. Set PATH to include your home directory at the beginning.
3. Try running connect. If it's vulnerable, you will get a root shell.

Comment: Thanks..I have just edited my last comment as I was mistaken. as @that guy from over there advised to run strings against the binary which revealed that it is using "scp" to connect to the remote server. Thus, I have applied the above instructions against "scp" instead of "ssh". But I get this error "scp: /tobecopied/*: No such file or directory"

Comment: I searched out and seems the problem with copied /bin/bash. I even tried /bin/sh but no luck. what other binaries that can be renamed to scp safely and still  give me access to shell instead of normal shells?

Comment: @AhmedTaher You could write your own quick and dirty shell script that just ignores the arguments and forks a shell.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I was just thinking of already compiled binaries on the system that could do the job. anway, I  tried metasploit reverse payload binary and it worked for me. Thanks guys for the hep

Comment: @AhmedTaher  I might be facing the same machine but again just getting scp: file/tobecopied/*: No such file or directory. What msfvenom payload did you use?